# Is there a way is CSS to check if a child element has a sibling?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way is CSS to check if a child element has a sibling? Example:

```html
<div class="node">
    <div class="node-child"></div>
    <div class="node-child"></div>
    <div class="node-child"></div>
</div>
```

I basically want to edit the last child, but only if it hasn't got another proceeding it AND it's an odd number. So if there is 4 `node-child` do nothing, but if there is only 3 do X

Comment: `* ~ :last-child` ?

Comment: So if it hasn't one preceeding it's alone right? then you're looking for `:only-child` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child

Comment: or `:first-child:last-child` ;) if it stands alone , it is both

Comment: You've just completely changed the foundation of the question, will look to update

Comment: if it's the last child and has no preceding how can you have 4 nodes?

Comment: I believed I've answered my own question anyway `:last-child:nth-child(odd) `

Comment: So you just wanted children that came last and are odd. Got it, fine, but that's not what you asked

Answer (score 1):

Sure, combine `:first-child` and `:last-child` into one selector:

```
.node-child:first-child:last-child {
    /* Styles for when it is one element with no siblings */
}
```

Or the opposite, which would be:

```
.node-child:first-child:not(:last-child),
.node-child:last-child:not(:first-child),
.node-child:not(:first-child):not(:lsat-child), {
   /* Styles for when there are more than one, i.e. ther are siblings */
}
```

To be even more succint for your specific case, use `:only-child` where the equivalents would be:

```
.node-child:only-child {
    /* Styles for when it is one element with no siblings */
}
```

And the equivalent opposite, even cleaner:

```
.node-child:not(:only-child) {
    /* Styles for when it is one element with no siblings */
}
```

It's perfectly safe to use `only-child`, assuming you're not supporting IE8 of course!

Comment: the last one will not work `:not(:first-child:last-child)`

Comment: I didn't explain very well, I've edited my question.